# Tensorflow queue runner - is it possible to queue a specific subset?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

In tensorflow, I plan to build some model and compare it to other baseline models with respect to different subsets of the training data. I.e. I would like to train my model and the baseline models with the same subsets of training data.

In the naive way queue-runner and TFreaders are implemented (e.g. [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt)), this requires duplicating the data per each selection of subsets, which is my case, will require to use very large amounts of disk space.

It will be best, if there would be a way to tell the queue to fetch only samples from a specified subset of ids, or to ignore samples if they are not part of a given subset of ids.

If I understand correctly ignoring samples is not trivial, because it will require to stitch samples from different reads to a single batch.

Does anybody knows a way to do that? Or can suggest an alternative approach which does not requires pre-loading all the training data into the RAM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encode your condition as part of `keep_input` parameter of [tf.train.maybe_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline#maybe_batch)